# gsub: Removing a special character at the end of a string in R

Tags: r

I am looking to replace all *s at the end of a string, in R.

```
txt <- c("arm","foot-ha-*","lefroo", "bafoobar*")
gsub("/\\*$/","",txt, perl=TRUE);
```

I would like to convert txt to be 
"arm" "foo-ha-" "lefroo" "bafoobar"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `/`s in the regex.

`gsub("\\*$", "", txt)`

Comment: you don't need the `g` as well.

Comment: The semicolon can go as well!

Comment: probably you should do: `sub("\\*+$", "", txt)` to take care of, for ex: `bla**`.

Comment: Some might want to `sub("[*]+$", "", txt)`